# Parse Object Query Design with GeoPoint

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have a parse query in swift and I am trying to run what may need to be a OR query along with a geopoint. Firstly, I can't seem to find any documentation on how objects are sorted by default when using a query like the below:

```
query.whereKey("postLocation", nearGeoPoint: newObjGeoPoint, withinMiles: miles)
```

If no other ordering is set on the query, do results come back closest to furthest away?

Also, when running this query I may not have as many results within a given distance so I would want to get all posts after this to add in to my table so a user can continue scrolling posts. Below is my current query but not sure of the best way to write it to allow all posts but sort by having posts closest in distance to me first and then all others after that.

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "posts")
query.whereKey("postLocation", nearGeoPoint: newObjGeoPoint, withinMiles: miles)
query.whereKey("forSale", equalTo:"yes")
// want to load only 30 at a time until user scrolls more
query.limit = maxPostLoad
// want to skip what we have already loaded into the view
query.skip = self.pageLoaded
```

Would it be better to have an OR query or sort by distance on all results returned when I start looping them? Getting stuck here with the best approach

Comment: There is no default order. So, if you don't set an order, It will come in a non predicable order. If you sort by distance and use the skip, you should be able to get the result you want.

Comment: I came across this, don't know how I missed it: https://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#geo-queries but looks like default is nearest to farthest is default sort if no other sorting is happening. But trying to think of how to best include other posts that may not have location set or are outside the boundaries to just provide more for a user to see